# why is it necessary to send pcm samples to ALSA?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, alsa, tinyalsa

I understand that if the hardware decoders are not present then we need to send pcm samples to alsa, but is it solely because of hardware limitation, or is there any requirement from ALSA as well ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a sample format that is

- [known to ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#gaa14b7f26877a812acbb39811364177f8), and
- supported by the device.